# How to simulate fake third party response for testing

Tags: linux, api, unit-testing, testing

Is there a way I can generate fake third API response ?

Why I want to generate fake API response?

1. Some third API have rete limit of calls. Example  twitter.
2. Testing with original third party API adds network delay.
3. Testing should not be affected if third party is down.
4. Generating same response everytime for writing test cases.

Currently we are solving this problem by manually writing code to generate same response for the API. But it is not feasible and expandable. If third party is changing API we need to re-write complete code again and as count of third party is getting increased. It will add lot of time for writing this code.

What type of solution I am looking for ?

Some time of network sniffing or simulator inside which I can run my app for one time and I can save response generated by third party API.

Comment: You might be able to use Fiddler to record sessions and replay them. Not sure if this is what you are after though :)

Comment: @leppie Sorry forget to add linux in tag list. I am looking solution for linux. 
I don't know about Fiddler but can I save request and response for future use. Some type of mapping for the request data and response data.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is just the right tool for you. Look at https://github.com/skrill/holoserve

It's written in Ruby, but runs as a standalone service can fake any http service at the HTTP-level. You can define request/response pairs along with variants of it (e.g. different parameters).

I'm using it to mock wbeservices during the tests.